# Exception handling with code and message in java

Tags: java, rest, exception

I want to write custom exception handling for my java code. I am using rest based service which returns a valid json response in case of success. In case of any exception, I want to return a proper json response with the error code and error message.

This is my Exception class

```
public class MyException extends Exception{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6823908633735492805L;

    protected String errorCode;

    protected String errorMessage;

    public MyException()
    {
        super();
    }

    public MyException(String errorCode)
    {
        super(errorCode, null);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public MyException(String errorMessage, String errorCode)
    {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public MyException(Throwable cause)
    {
        super(cause);
    }

    public String getErrorCode()
    {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage()
    {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public MyException(Throwable cause, String errorCode, String errorMessage)
    {
        super(cause);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

}
```

In my code, i am handling the Exception like below but I am getting *500 Internal Server Error*

```
}catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    throw new MyException("301",e.getMessage());            
}
```

Below is my rest api

```
@Path("{id}")
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Operation(operationId = "update")
@APIResponse(responseCode = "204")
public Response update(@Context SecurityContext context, String effort) throws MyException {
    try {
        service.update(effort);
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new MyException("301",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are u creating REST API also , are u using Spring or Jersey ?

Comment: Please share your rest service. I doubt that the MyException class is the issue.

Comment: I m using helidon...

Comment: I have updated my rest api...

Comment: It's not enough to just inherit `Exception`. You have to inherit `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom exception by

```
public class CustomException
      extends RuntimeException {
        public CustomException(String errorMessage) {
            super(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Next, In your method you can produce this exception by

```
}catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());            
}
```